# rxvt-unicode (urxvt) freezes when I try to paste a text with control characters from other X11 application

Tags: urxvt

My `~/.Xresources` below:

```
! urxvt
! URxvt.background: White
! URxvt.foreground: Black

URxvt.font: xft:Cica:size=10
URxvt.background: Black
URxvt.foreground: White
URxvt.title: rxvt

URxvt.scrollTtyOutput: false
URxvt.scrollWithBuffer: true
URxvt.scrollTtyKeypress: true
URxvt.secondaryScreen: 1
URxvt.secondaryScroll: 0

! URxvt.perl-ext-common: clipboard
! URxvt.clipboard.autocopy: true
! URxvt.keysym.M-c: perl:clipboard:copy
! URxvt.keysym.M-v: perl:clipboard:paste
```

I ran `xrdb -query` to list what X resources are loaded:

```
URxvt.background:   Black
URxvt.font: xft:Cica:size=10
URxvt.foreground:   White
URxvt.scrollTtyKeypress:    true
URxvt.scrollTtyOutput:  false
URxvt.scrollWithBuffer: true
URxvt.secondaryScreen:  1
URxvt.secondaryScroll:  0
URxvt.title:    rxvt
```

I also tried `gdb` with `r` and `bt full`. I had to do nothing but `^C` from original terminal when called rxvt stucks when prompting with such as two lines of text with yellow background `Pasting 1 control characters, continue? (y/n/p)` and `海の中のイラスト（背景素材）\n`:

```
$ gdb urxvt
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from urxvt...

This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
  <https://debuginfod.archlinux.org>
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n]) 
Debuginfod has been disabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled off' to .gdbinit.
(No debugging symbols found in urxvt)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/urxvt 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
urxvt: unable to create fontset for input method, try "-pt Root". Continuing.
[Detaching after fork from child process 29953]
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7721177 in epoll_wait () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007ffff7721177 in epoll_wait () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x000055555559b1f7 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000055555559f109 in ev_run ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x000055555557e6f0 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb)
```

I downloaded and installed `rxvt-unicode` on Arch GNU/Linux via `yay` package manager, and here is my version:

```
Version         : 9.31-1
```

Whichever I press C-M-v keys or middle button of my mouse, this happened.

The following extension did never help me:

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: clipboard
URxvt.clipboard.autocopy: true
URxvt.keysym.M-c: perl:clipboard:copy
URxvt.keysym.M-v: perl:clipboard:paste
```